# Javascript - Parse string based upon keys in dictionary / object

Tags: javascript, string, function, dictionary, parsing

In my React program, suppose I had the following dictionary / object

```
const myDict = {
    "a":"Value 1",
    "b":"Value 2",
    "hello":"Value 3",
    "Bye":"Value 4"
}
```

(note that no keys have values existing in any other keys - For example, no key can contain the `a` letter since that is a different key)

And I will be receiving a string that will **ONLY CONSIST OF PERMUTATIONS OF THE KEYS TO THIS OBJECT**, so, for example, possible string entries will be:

- "abhellob"
- "ababByeahello"
- "ByehelloByeba"
- etc.

And I am looking to create a function that will break the input string down into its constituent parts based upon the keys of `myDict`.

So, for example,

- `"abhellob"` would become `["a", "b", "hello", "b"]`

How can I create such a function? I've tried, but am getting lost with having to deal with different length keys to `myDict` and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression that alternates between the different keys would do the trick.

```js
const myDict = {
    "a":"Value 1",
    "b":"Value 2",
    "hello":"Value 3",
    "Bye":"Value 4"
}
const pattern = new RegExp(
  Object.keys(myDict).join('|'),
  'g'
);
console.log("abhellob".match(pattern));
console.log("ababByeahello".match(pattern));
console.log("ByehelloByeba".match(pattern));
```

(If some keys could have character overlap, a start would be to sort the keys so the longest ones come first.)

```js
const myDict = {
    "a":"Value 1",
    "b":"Value 2",
    "hello":"Value 3",
    "Bye":"Value 4"
}
const pattern = new RegExp(
  Object.keys(myDict)
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
    .join('|'),
  'g'
);
console.log("abhellob".match(pattern));
console.log("ababByeahello".match(pattern));
console.log("ByehelloByeba".match(pattern));
```

Comment: The sort is a nice touch but according to the question it's not necessary since no key can contain another key. Might be worth adding a comment next to it just to clarify. Upvoted Regardless

Comment: @nickzoum Oh, you're right, I saw the `a` and `b` keys and was worried about them possibly appearing in other keys, but capital letters are different from lowercase.

Comment: FYI due to this being Regex, this breaks when the dict keys contain Regex expressions. For example: `"[":"Value 1",`. Dynamically generating Regex queries off of user input is generally unwise.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Can be fixed with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711, but doesn't look necessary here

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without Regex:

```js
function getFragments(entryString){
  const myDict = {
"a":"Value 1",
"b":"Value 2",
"hello":"Value 3",
"Bye":"Value 4"
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(myDict);
  
  const result = [];
  let remainingString = entryString;
  while (remainingString) {
const nextWord = keys.find(key => remainingString.startsWith(key));
if (!nextWord) throw new Error("Couldn't match with word");

result.push(nextWord);
remainingString = remainingString.slice(nextWord.length);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getFragments("abhellob"));
console.log(getFragments("ababByeahello"));
console.log(getFragments("ByehelloByeba"));
```